# Warranty for HVAC replacement parts?

Tags: hvac, repair, replacement

I had a problem with my [Trane](https://www.trane.com/index.html) furnace, and a technician from Trane-certified service company had to replace the blower motor. When I asked him about warranty on this motor, he told me that replacement parts are normally installed without warranty.

Is it true?

(I'm in New Jersey, USA)

**UPDATE**. The original warranty has already expired.

Comment: If you originally paid using CC then you might get extended coverage under the cc insurance.

Comment: the motor manufacturer may provide replacement if motor fails within 90 days or a year ... ask

Comment: @jsotola - I asked and he told me that if the motor fails next day, then I'll need to buy a new one. It seems to me too unfair, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: that seems unethical ... ask for the invoice for the motor purchase, so that you know when the motor was purchased and from where it was purchased ... contact the seller to see if they provide warranty to the service company

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to refer to your warranty documents.  The terms and coverages will be stated in gory detail there.

But generally parts replace under warranty will be covered under the original unit's warranty.  So if you had a 2 year warranty and the blower motor was replaced after 1 year.  The new motor as well as the rest of the covered parts would be covered for another year.

But again, the details are in your warranty papers.  Nothing said here will make any difference to that.

The OP later added:

> The warranty for the original installation has already expired, so I
> had to pay full price for the blower.

In that case it's entirely a transaction between you and the servicing company. If they offer no warranty on their parts or labor then my recommendation is that you choose another company that does. In my experience there is usually some language printed on the invoice that details any warranty for services and installed parts.  In my experience that is often 30 days or so.